# Kernel error: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, manjaro, debugging, journalctl

I am always getting this error at boot. Is there anything major, and if it is, how could be fixed?
I get that it has something to do with my AMD GPU. Here is the setup I have:

- Cpu:
  AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G, 2586 MHz
- GPU:
  ATI Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics],
  AMD ATI Radeon R5 M230 / R7 M260DX / Radeon 520 Mobile
- 4GB RAM, 250GB SSD
- OS: Linux manjaro 5.9.16-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 21 22:00:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Also here's the kernel journal from the last boot:

```
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
 Subject: A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has begun execution
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has begun execution.

 The job identifier is 1270.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd-backlight[875]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
The unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
 Subject: A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 1270 and the job result is failed.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1615879497.236:64): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1...
 Subject: A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has begun execution
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has begun execution.
 
 The job identifier is 1276.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd-backlight[876]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video1': No such device
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 The unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1.
 Subject: A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
 A start job for unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service has finished with a failure.
The job identifier is 1276 and the job result is failed.
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1615879497.263:65): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Mar 16 09:24:57 manjaro ModemManager[412]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:03:00.0': not supported by any plugin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and add the below parameters to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX:`

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

##### Do not forget to run `update-grub` afterwards.

###### For me that solved the issue! I had it on an ATI/AMD, a rather old gpu. Also I wanted to mention this, didn't break the ability to adjust the screen brightness.

##### May your htop stats be low and your beard grow long!